# Accessing LinkedIn API from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api

I am building an app with Angular.js accesing the LinkedIn API. What happens is that when I do a call to the API, the model does not get refreshed inmediately, but after I do another change on the screen. For example, I have binded the API call to a button, but I have to press it twice for the screen to get the data refreshed. This is my controller:

```
    angbootApp.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getCommitData = function() {
            IN.API.Profile("me").fields(
                    [ "id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl",
                            "publicProfileUrl" ]).result(function(result) {
                //set the model
                $scope.jsondata = result.values[0];
            }).error(function(err) {
                $scope.error = err;
            });
        };
    });
```

And this is my button and a link with the content:

```
<div>
  <a href="{{jsondata.publicProfileUrl}}">{{jsondata.firstName}}</a>
  <form ng-submit="getCommitData()">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Data">
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Explanation on how I did it [here](http://codepioneer.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/angularjs-log-in-with-linkedin/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call **$scope.$apply** when retrieving the results/error

```
angbootApp.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getCommitData = function() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(
                [ "id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl",
                        "publicProfileUrl" ]).result(function(result) {
            //set the model
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.jsondata = result.values[0];
            });
        }).error(function(err) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.error = err;
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Anything outside angular world does not trigger automatic refresh of the views.
See [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply)